# How to make dropdown submenu close on touch devices ie (i-pad) in React

Tags: reactjs, navbar, styled-components

I want the dropdown to close when I tap outside the dropdown.

How can I achieve this?

```
<ListItem
  role="menuitem"
  onClick={() => setNavOpen('about')}
  onMouseEnter={() => setNavOpen('about')}
  onMouseLeave={() => setNavOpen('')}>
    <div
     role="button"
     aria-haspopup={navOpen === 'about' ? 'true' : 'false'}
     style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }}>
       About us
     </div>
</ListItem>
```

Answer (score 0):

`onMouseEnter` and `onMouseLeave` aren't what do you want, they are triggered once the user just pass the mouse over the element.

There is some libs that implements this for you, check some of it [here](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=click%20outside)

Comment: `onMouseEnter` & `onMouseLeave` are for desktop. Thanks for your answer.